# On clicking a command button, 2 dialog boxes with same widgetVar are getting opened

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces in my JSF Web project and there is one situation where I want to render a command button on some condition and when it is rendered then on click of that command button, I want one dialog box to get opened. This dialog should consists of one dropdown and when any value is selected from the dropdown, then one form beneath that dropdown should appear with the form fields related to the value selected in the dropdown.

The code I am trying:

```
<p:dataTable id="paramTable" value="#{testDesignView.paramlist}" var="pr" scrollable="true" liveResize="true" resizableColumns="true" style="font-size:10px;margin-bottom:0 ;min-height:200px" scrollRows="3"  scrollHeight="120" >
  <f:facet name="header">
        Parameters
    </f:facet>
      <p:column headerText="Key" style="width:141.406px;">
        <h:outputText value="#{pr.key}" />
    </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="Value" style="width:197.594px;">      
       <p:inputText value="#{pr.value}"  ondblclick="try{PF('op').show();}catch(e){};showPanel([{name:'selectedparam', value:'#{pr.key}'}]);" >
       <p:ajax listener="#{testDesignView.updateStepRow(pr)}"
                                     />
       </p:inputText>
       <p:commandButton rendered="#{pr.key == 'Body'}" icon="pi pi-window-maximize" actionListener="#{testDesignView.viewApiBody(pr)}" update="tm:bodyDialog:tcApiBody" oncomplete="PF('bodydlg').show();" style="margin-left:10px;"/>
     
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
     <p:commandButton value="Advanced Settings" rendered="#{testDesignView.restFlag}" oncomplete="PF('authSettingsdlg1').show();"/>
    </f:facet>
     </p:dataTable>


 <p:dialog header="Advanced Settings" widgetVar="authSettingsdlg1" resizable="false" modal="true">
            <p:panel id="authTypePanel" style="width:1200px;height:500px">
                  <p:selectOneMenu id="authType" value="#{testDesignView.currentAuthType}" style="width:1020px">
                  <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{testDesignView.loadAuthForm()}"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                     <f:selectItems value="#{testDesignView.authTypesDropdownList}" var="authTypeNm" itemLabel="#{authTypeNm}" itemValue="#{authTypeNm}" />
                  </p:selectOneMenu>
                  </p:panel>
                  <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Access Token" style="margin-top: 5px;"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" style="margin-top: 5px;" oncomplete="PF('authSettingsdlg1').hide();"/>
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

public void loadAuthForm() {
        System.out.println("loadAuthForm method invoked");
        System.out.println("currentAuthType selected--> "+currentAuthType);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and how I can avoid opening these 2 dialogs of same widgetVar on click of below command button which is rendered on one condition?

```
<p:commandButton value="Advanced Settings" rendered="#{testDesignView.restFlag}" oncomplete="PF('authSettingsdlg1').show();"/>
```

Also, the ajax value change listener method is not getting invoked when any value is selected from the select dropdown of the dialog box with widget var 'authSettingsdlg1'. and when the cross button of one dialog is clicked, it closes the other duplicate dialog too.

Also, How can I change the form values and load a form just below the dropdown in the dialog box on the basis of the value selected from dropdown? for eg: if Basic is selected from dropdown, then form below it should get opened with 2 input text boxes fields of basic username and basic password. Similarly other form fields in dialog will change as per the selected value in dropdown.

Screenshot of 2 duplicate dialogs of same widgetVar

[image]

Comment: What's your complete page code? Do you have a single form that includes everything? Maybe an `appendTo="@body"` to your dialog can solve(PF version?). Try to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303961/ajax-listener-event-valuechange-seems-to-be-firing-onclick-instead-of-onchange) for the event question. About the last one, try including in different containers, with respective rendered checks, and update an item that contains both, in your ajax.

Comment: @WoAiNii I have one testMgmt.xhtml file that includes one form and inside the form of this xhtml, it includes two other xhtml files 'testDesign.xhtml' and 'navigation.xhtml' in different div containers. I created the command button inside one div of testDesign.xhtml and on click of that btn, i want the dialog to get opened which is defined in testMgmt.xhtml. I tried using appendTo-"@body" but it didn't worked for me. My PF version is 7.0. Still 2 dialogs getting opened on click of one same command button.

Comment: @WoAiNii I have one testMgmt.xhtml file that includes one form and inside the form of this xhtml, it includes two other xhtml files 'testDesign.xhtml' and 'navigation.xhtml' in different div containers. I created the command button inside one div of testDesign.xhtml and on click of that btn, i want the dialog to get opened which is defined in testMgmt.xhtml. I tried using appendTo-"@body" but it didn't worked for me. My PF version is 7.0. Still 2 dialogs getting opened on click of one same command button.

Comment: can you post the code of these 3 xhtml? Remove everything unrelated, so we can reproduce your scenario.